# Equally align hanging chapter and section numbers

Tags: memoir, alignment

I am using the memoir class hangnum features for chapters and sections, here is a minimal example:

```latex
\documentclass{memoir}

\makechapterstyle{hangnum}{
  \setlength{\chapindent}{0.8 cm} % <-- What should this be?
  \renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{}
  \renewcommand*{\chapternamenum}{}
  \renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{\noindent\llap{\makebox[\chapindent][l]{\chapnumfont \thechapter}}}
  \renewcommand*{\afterchapternum}{}}

\chapterstyle{hangnum}
\hangsecnum

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section Uno}
\subsection{Subsection Eins}
\section{Section Duo}
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to properly align the numbers for chapters and sections without just guessing a length?

[image]

Comment: Please post a full minimal example instead of a sniplet where we have to guess the rest.

Comment: Besides that the default section separation is `\quad`. `\hangsecnum` is the same as running `\def\@seccntformat##1{\llap{\csname the##1\endcsname\quad}`

Comment: @daleif Thanks for your feedback, I've updated the question with a full minimal example :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you can do (just remove `\T` it is only there so show where things are).

As mentioned in a comment, sections use `\quad` as the spacer. But `\quad` depends on the current font size, so since `\chapnumfont` and the sec font size are not the same, we cannot just use `\quad`. Instead, we use a fixed width spacer.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\newlength\secspacer
% we do not want em here as it changes with the font size
\setlength\secspacer{12pt} 

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\myhangsecnum}{%
  \def\@seccntformat##1{\llap{\csname the##1\endcsname\kern\secspacer}}}
\makeatother

\newcommand\T{%
  \llap{\smash{\rule[-15cm]{0.1pt}{20cm}}}%
}


\makechapterstyle{hangnum}{
%  \setlength{\chapindent}{1em} % <-- What should this be?
  \renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{}
  \renewcommand*{\chapternamenum}{}
  \renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{\noindent\llap{\chapnumfont \thechapter\T\kern\secspacer}}
  \renewcommand*{\afterchapternum}{}
}

\chapterstyle{hangnum}
\myhangsecnum

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section Uno}
\subsection{Subsection Eins}
\section{Section Duo}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I know comments are fore feedback, but since I can not upvote yet, thank you very much for the detailed and quality answer, I've learned a lot from it :)